# asp.net mvc convert iqueryble to particular object

Tags: asp.net-mvc

how can i convert the particular **postquery** to my Post object , so it can be added to the list **posts** .

```
            List<Post> posts = new List<Post>();
            var postquery= from post in postrepository.GetAllPosts()
                           select post;
            posts.Add();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
posts.AddRange(postQuery);
```

Should work.

List supports adding an IEnumerable collection, and an IQueryable collection is also an IEnumerable collection, so you should be able to use AddRange here.